# soapで出力された結果をjson形式に変換したいのですが、エラーメッセージが出力され変換できない

Tags: python

zeepを利用してsoapサーバーから取得したデータをjson形式に変換する方法を探しております。
色々調べたのですが、自分では解決出来ず質問させて頂きました。
初歩的な質問かと思いますが、どうぞよろしくお願い致します

soapサーバーからの出力結果

```
{
    'header': {
        'sessionID': '1234'
    },
    'body': {
        'return': {
            'result_code': 0,
            'result_data': 'Extension=1234|Type=5678,
            'message_text': None
        }
    }
}
```

試したコード

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth  
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
import json


session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth("abcd", "78910")
client = Client('http://1.1.1.1/sms/Service.php?wsdl', transport=Transport(session=session))




result = str(client.service.submitrequest("station","display").replace('\'', '\"')
result_js = json.loads(result)
```

エラーメッセージ

```
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line x(数字) column x(数字) (char 2779)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージの一部が伏せ字になっているので推測になりますが、`None` という文字列のデコードでエラーが発生している様です。なので、`None` という文字列を空文字列(empty string)を表す `""` に置き換えます。
※ 単純置換では、ある問題が想定されますが現時点では以下の通りです。

```py
import json

json_text = """
{
  'header': {
    'sessionID': '1234'
  },
  'body': {
    'return': {
      'result_code': 0,
      'result_data': 'Extension=1234|Type=5678',
      'message_text': None
    }
  }
}
""".replace("'", '"')

json_text = json_text.replace('None', r'""')
json_dict = json.loads(json_text)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(json_dict, sort_dicts=False)

#
{'header': {'sessionID': '1234'},
 'body': {'return': {'result_code': 0,
                     'result_data': 'Extension=1234|Type=5678',
                     'message_text': ''}}}
```

Comment: ご教示頂いた内容で無事目的を目的の内容で出力することが出来ました。
本当にありがとうございます。助かりました!